# Problems on bounded finite intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

1.Prove that if $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)=0$ and $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(2 x)-f(x)}{x}=0$, then $\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0$.

2.Suppose that $f$ defined on $(a,+\infty)$ is bounded on each finite interval $(a, b), a<b$. Prove that if $\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=l$, then also $\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=l$.

My approach for first problem:-

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrarily. By assumption there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\frac{\left|f(x)-f\left(\frac{1}{2} x\right)\right|}{|x|}<\varepsilon, \quad \text { whenever } 0<|x|<\delta
$$
Hence, for $0<|x|<\delta$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| &=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{f(x)-f\left(\frac{1}{\left.2^{n+1} x\right)}\right.}{x}\right| \\
& \leq \varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\left|f\left(\frac{x}{2^{k-1}}\right)-f\left(\frac{x}{2^{k}}\right)\right|}{\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}|x|} \\
& \leq \varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} f=2 \epsilon
\end{aligned}
$$

Kindly cheak this and please give hints or solution for the second problem also give another hints or solution for first problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parts looks fine.

For the second part let $n \leq x <n+1$ and write $\frac {f(x)} x$ as $$\frac {f(x)-f(x-1)} x$$ $$+\frac {(f(x-1)-f(x-2))+\cdots+(f(x-(n-1))-f(x-n))} n \frac n x $$ $$+\frac {f(x-n)} x.$$ By assumption, the first and the last terms tend to $0$. Use Cesaro's Theorem to see that the second term tends to $l$. [Note that $n \to \infty$ and $\frac n x \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$].